# How this code blocks work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's see examples:

**first:**

```
var user = {
  firstName: "John",
  sayHi: function() {
  alert( this.firstName );
  }
};

setTimeout(function() {
  user.sayHi(); // John
}, 1000);
```

**second:**

```
var user = {
  firstName: "John",
  sayHi: function() {
  alert( this.firstName );
  }
};

setTimeout(user.sayHi, 1000);// undefined
```

Why in the second example ***undefined***? And how does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a function reference to a `setTimeout` function, the passed function reference will be executed in the `window`'s scope. So `window.firstName` will be `undefined` as you don't have any property in `window` object like that.

```
var user = {
  firstName: "John",
  sayHi: function() {
  alert( this.firstName );
  }
};

setTimeout(user.sayHi.bind(user), 1000);
```

So as you can see in the above code, you have to explicitly bind the scope to the function reference. And also you can use the traditional way, that is using an anonymous function like below,

```
setTimeout(function(){ user.sayHi(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you but i don't understand how works your example with anonymous function? How that saves context?

Comment: @JimButton With the anonymous function, It becomes a closure. I mean the object user. But with the first case, Internally setTimeout will call the passed function reference like `reference.call(scope)` where scope will be the window if it was not overridden. so this.firstName would be similar to window.firstName.

Comment: Thank you for your help!